# I can not understand the kernel internal representation of PID

Tags: c, linux, kernel

The Linux kernel uses struct pid to represent PID in kernel space.The C code is below.

```
struct pid
{
atomic_t count;
/* lists of tasks that use this pid */
struct hlist_head tasks[PIDTYPE_MAX];
int level;
struct upid numbers[1];
};
```

I can not really understand why the member tasks can represent "the lists of tasks".Since task_struct is the kernel internal representation of task,and one task only uses one task_struct.Why can more than one task share a "struct pid"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because more than one task can be part of the same process. Consider, for example, a multi-threaded process using a 1-to-1 threading library like NPTL. It has a single process ID, is a single process, but consists of multiple entities scheduled by the kernel.

Comment: Yup. And while it may have just one "PID" you can still see multiple "lightweight process IDs" in `ps` if you use the `-L` option (I think that's the right option on Linux).

Comment: @JohnZwinck You can call them "TID"s or "task IDs".